# Does anyone know free DIY ultralight plans?

Tags: ultralight

Is anybody aware of  open source plans for an ultralight that can be made out of standarized aluminium/wooden parts without welding?

Answer (score 1):

Most designers of successful ultralight designs (rightfully) believe they should be paid for their efforts.  If nothing else, this provides a financial buffer against potential legal actions.

That said, there is at least one open source ultralight glider family: the [Goat](http://m-sandlin.info/goat/goat.htm).  It meets your design criteria in general, in that it's designed not to require specialized parts or materials.

There are cases of builders adding an engine to versions of the Goat or to Goat-derived designs -- the [Bloop](http://m-sandlin.info/bloop/bloop.htm) is one such -- but I'm not aware if the plans for those modification are freely avilable.

Comment: The problem with the Goat is if you want to motorize it you have to increase the GW by at least 50lbs and will have to beef up the structure.

Comment: Might be why there aren't many motorized Goats or Bloops around.  You have to know what you're doing to build one, never mind motorize it.

Comment: I have the plans and it is a pretty simple design with easy to make parts; but there are a lot of them.  There is a guy in NY state who has a motorized ultralight based on the Goat, who sells kits, but it's significantly redesigned and heavier, and the vids of it flying with fairly small motor aren't very impressive.  The Mitchell Wing can be a very good choice for a soarable ultralight. Simple wood structure, twitchy but manageable in pitch and safe to fly if you learn properly, ideal for electric power as an ultralight motorglider.  Problem is trying to find plans.